# java sax program doesn't go to startElement() method

Tags: java, xml, sax

i'm trying to use the sax parser with customized DefaultHandler, but the strange thing that startElement() method in the dHandler is never invoked. endDocument() works as it should, but it prints

```
Total elements:0
```

while my xml-file has 11 elements of type "state".

if even i place total++ outside the if statement, so it gonna increment everytime startElement() is invoked, it still says 0 elements.

please help me on that, thank you

```
if(e.getSource()==open)
    {
        JFileChooser chooseFile=new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = chooseFile.showOpenDialog(wnd);
         if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = chooseFile.getSelectedFile();

                //This is where a real application would open the file.
                parser.parse(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(file)));
                DocumentImpl document = (DocumentImpl)parser.getDocument();
                Node root = document.getLastChild();
                AllElements allelements = new AllElements();
                NodeIteratorImpl iterator =(NodeIteratorImpl)document.createNodeIterator(root,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, (NodeFilter)allelements, true);
                Node n;
                states.removeAll(states);
                while ((n = iterator.nextNode()) != null)
                {

                    if(n.getNodeName().equals("state"))
                    {
                        NamedNodeMap attrs = n.getAttributes();
                        NodeList children=n.getChildNodes();
                        State newState=new State(attrs.item(0).getNodeValue(),
                                attrs.item(1).getNodeValue(),attrs.item(2).getNodeValue(),attrs.item(3).getNodeValue(),children.item(0).getTextContent());
                        states.add(newState);

                    }

                }
                Collections.sort(states,new StateComparator());
                mod.setRowCount(states.size());
                mod.setColumnCount(5);
                for(int i=0;i<states.size();i++)
                {
                    mod.setValueAt(states.get(i).abbr, i, 0);

                    mod.setValueAt(states.get(i).name, i, 1);
                    mod.setValueAt(states.get(i).population_2k10, i, 2);
                    mod.setValueAt(states.get(i).rank_2k, i, 3);
                    mod.setValueAt(states.get(i).census_1990, i, 4);
                }

                mean=0;
                max=MAXIMUM;
                min=MINIMUM;
                count=0;
                  total=0;
                  SAXParserFactory parserFact = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parserS = parserFact.newSAXParser();
        DefaultHandler dHandler = new DefaultHandler(){
            public void startElement(String uri, String name, String element, Attributes atri)
                            {
                if (element.equals("state")){
                    total++;
                }
            }
            public void endDocument(){
                System.out.println("Total elements: " + total);
            }
        };
                  parserS.parse(file, dHandler);
                  meanL.setText("mean="+mean);
                  maxL.setText("max="+max);
                  minL.setText("min="+min);
                  countL.setText("count="+total);
        } else {

        }

     }
```

Comment: as an aside you should not use the implementation classes of sax, like DocumentImpl. Use the interface Document.

Comment: how does your code compile in this first place? Your `DefaultHandler` implementation is an anonymous local class; the `total` variable being referenced in it has to be `final`.

Answer (score 16):

Please check the import statement for the Attribute parameter, it should be:

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
```

Regards

Comment: Nice, Eclipse first choice for autocomplete is java.util.jar; changing the reference fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you haven't overridden the default `startElement()` correctly.  If you add an `@Override` annotation to the method you should not get a compile-time error.  If you do, then the declaration of `startElement(...)`  (which you didn't show) is incorrect.

EDIT: Your `startElement` declaration needs to look like this:

```
void startElement(
    String uri, 
    String localName, 
    String qName, 
    Attributes attributes)
```

The parameter names can be different, but the number of arguments and their types must match exactly.

Comment: that's exactly what you have described!  i have tried to add @Override before - and it gave me error. could you please give me a hint on what to change?

Comment: Please edit your post to show how you declared your handler class, and the declaration of the `startElement()` method.  The @Override annotation is there to help you find exactly this kind of problem.  If you think you're overriding something it tells you if you didn't declare it correctly.

Comment: i haven't declared it anywhere - DefaultHandler is an adapter class, so i just redefined the methods. in the DefaultHandler this method is declared as:  public void startElement (String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes), ie exactly with the same parameters i've used.

Comment: You must extend DefaultHandler somewhere.  It's not an adapter but an abstract base class which you must subclass to define your XML handler.  What is the declaration of the class that contains `startElEment()`?

Comment: wow, i came to solution, there are several types of attribute classes and i was import the wrong one (automatically, in netbeans - you know, just clicking import not thinking about it much). thank you and everyone who responded for help! i appreciate

Comment: It's customary on SO to "accept" an answer that solves your problem by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant that the name of the element is 'state'. If so, the following line in the DefaultHandler.startElement implementation should be:

```
if (name.equals("state")){
    total++;
}
```

instead of

```
if (element.equals("state")){
    total++;
}
```

The third parameter to the startElement method is actually the qName. It will be empty, if no namespace prefix exists; if a prefix is present, then it will be populated.

**Edit**

It does not appear that the original code will compile, at least not against the Oracle/Sun Java 6 compiler that I used. Here's what the implementation of the DefaultHandler class ought to look like, if the total elements were to be counted:

```
DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

    public int total = 0;

    public void startElement(String uri, String name, String qName,
            Attributes atri) {
        if (qName.equals("state")) {
            total++;
        }
    }

    public void endDocument() {
        System.out.println("Total elements: " + total);
    }
};
```

Note that the total variable is now a member of the anonymous class. If it weren't then it has to be declared as final in the outer class, which would make it immutable (rendering the increment operation as illegal). One cannot however, access the total variable from outside the anonymous class though. I would suggest extending the DefaultHandler class in a different class, and to use that handler implementation, to keep things simple.

Comment: yes, i have tried that - but it gets exactly the same result i've described - "Total elements: 0".  it even says "Total elements: 0" when i remove this if-statement and leave only total++